# Upgrading google-services gives me "No matching client found" error

Tags: android, gradle, upgrade

When I am upgrading my project from

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.12'
```

it is giving me error
"No matching client found for package name ...."

My project has lots of flavors, and also, it is a library project, if this helps.

Can you tell me the fix?

Answer (score 0):

If your applicationId is different between your buildTypes, you can add those particular artifacts to specific dependency flavor like releaseImplementation for example.